# SQL for different date data manipulation

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have two  tables (Customers and Invoices). **I want to know newest customers based on their first invoice date for x month**. For example, a customer might have joined/registered in November but it is possible that he has placed his FIRST ORDER in January. So he is a new customer for my criteria.
Sample tables are given below:
[image: e]

**DESIRED RESULTS:**
Below is just one example for above sample data. C5 customer joined in August 2019 but he placed his first order in January 2020. So for me, he is a new customer.
[image]

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect.

Comment: Desired results would help.

Comment: Question edited with desired reuslts. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on customers that have placed their first order after a given date, just use aggregation:

```
select customer, min(date) first_invoice_date
from invoices
group by customer
having first_invoice_date > @somedate
```

You can adapt (or remove) the `having` clause as needed.

If you want the details of the customer (eg its name and coutry), then you can join the customers table:

```
select c.*, o.first_invoice_date
from customers c
inner join (
    select customer, min(date) first_invoice_date
    from invoices
    group by customer
    having first_invoice_date > @somedate
) i on i.customer = c.id
```

Comment: I think we should count number of invoices for each customer. If count is 1, he is a new customer. It's little tricky, customer registered in the past, but he placed his first order in January 2020. 

So count all customer invoices, if count is 1 then check if the count is in Jan 2020, bingo, he is our new customer.

I don't know how to write query for this above statement.

Comment: @hammadshahir: the second query should give you the results that you want (you can remove the `having` clause for testing). Please give it a try.